# How do I show that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ defined by $x_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+5}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I show that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ defined by $x_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+5}$ converges?

I know that it converges to $0$ because the denominator approaches infinity as $n$ tends to infinity. However, I also know that $(-1)^n$ is divergent.

Comment: $-1 \le (-1)^n \le 1$ . Do you know the squeeze theorem?

Comment: Note that the series is absolutely convergent as $\frac{1}{n^2+5} \le \frac{1}{n^2}, \forall n \ge 1$

Comment: are you considering the series or the sequence?

Comment: I made a mistake. It should be sequence, not series.

Comment: @Outlier Yes I see that now!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let use squeeze theorem with $-|x_n|\le x_n \le |x_n|$ and

$$0\le |x_n|\le \frac{1}{n^2+5} $$

Comment: How do we know to take the absolute value though?

Comment: @Outlier The key point is that $$|x_n| \to 0 \iff x_n \to 0$$

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you come back to the epsilon-delta definition of convergence you are interested whether $|x_n-\ell|<\epsilon$

When $\ell=0$ this results in studying if we have $|x_n|<\epsilon$, and you can see that the $(-1)^n$ factor does not matter since it is killed by the absolute value.

Thus $|x_n|\to 0\iff x_n\to 0$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2+5}=0$$
and$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-1}{(2n+1)^2+5}=0$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0\implies x_n\quad \text{ is convergent}$$